# Не масштабируется текст при использовании единиц вьюпорта

Tags: html, шрифты, масштабирование

Изучаю отзывчивую верстку, на [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_responsive_text.asp) первый пример - с использованием единиц вьюпорта:

```html
<h1 style="font-size:10vw;">Responsive Text</h1>

<p style="font-size:5vw;">Resize the browser window to see how the text size scales.</p>

<p style="font-size:5vw;">Use the "vw" unit when sizing the text. 10vw will set the size to 10% of the viewport width.</p>

<p>Viewport is the browser window size. 1vw = 1% of viewport width. If the viewport is 50cm wide, 1vw is 0.5cm.</p>
```

(размеры шрифта заголовка и первых двух абзацах заданы в vw)

Но я столкнулся с проблемой, что при использовании единиц вьюпорта (vw) мой шрифт не увеличивается при `Ctrl` + `+` и `Ctrl` + `-`. Масштабирование работает только с пикселями, rem-ами и процентами. Но что, если мне некомфортно читать текст, который я не могу масштабировать вышеописанной комбинацией клавиш? Можно ли как-то сделать отзывчивый шрифт, который может мастабироваться юзером? И как вообще обстоит дело с масштабированием шрифта на мобилках?

P.S: Сейчас проверил на мобильном Google Chrome - вроде масштабируется, разве что заголовок очень слабо масштабируется, вот скрины - первый скрин с выкрученным в минимум (50%) шрифтом в настройках браузера, а второй скрин - с выкрученным в максимум (200%) шрифтом соответственно:
[image: скрин с 50% масштаба шрифта]
[image: скрин с 200% масштаба шрифта]
[Вот GitHub, если кому интересно.](https://github.com/IcEWaRRiOr01/Responsive-Font-Size)

P.P.S: да, я добавил строку `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` в `<head>`

Вопрос: как масштабировать шрифт, если он задан в единицах вьюпорта?

Comment: Ну так не задавайте шрифт в единицах вьюпорта. Очевидно что 1/100 ширины экрана не меняется при масштабировании

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/linearly-scale-font-size-with-css-clamp-based-on-the-viewport/